# how to refactor duplicate API calls into a single API call?

Tags: reactjs, rest, backend

I am pretty new to building full-stack applications, and I could like to avoid duplicating code in order to build the following to perform the calls in react my endpoints can be called like the following `/api/v1/feeds/list/?page=${page}` or `api/v1/feeds/list/?search=${query}` , but I would like to joing `?page=${page}&?search=${query}` since `search` param is optional . I just want to make a single api call

```
async function fetchFeed(page) {
    return api.get(`http://localhost:8001/api/v1/feeds/list/?page=${page}`);
  }
  
  async function searchQuery(query) {
    return api.get(`http://localhost:8001/api/v1/feeds/list/?search=${query}`);
  }

  const Main = () => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);
    const [feedCount, setfeedCount] = useState(0);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(3)
  
    const showMoreItems = () => {
      setVisible(prevValue => prevValue + 3);
    }
  
    const browse = (page) =>  {
      fetchFeed(page)
      .then(function(response){
        setfeedCount(response.data.count)
        setFeed(response.data.results)
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  
    // fetches data
    const fetchData = (search) => {
      searchQuery(search)
        .then((response) => {
          setFeed(response.data.results)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
  
    const handleSearch = (e) =>{
      fetchData(e.target.value);
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      browse(currentPage)
      fetchData(feed);
    }, [currentPage]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd pass an object with both `page` and `query`, which both default to the empty string - and if empty, don't include them in the fetched URL:

```
async function fetchFeed({ page = '', query = '' }) {
    return api.get(`http://localhost:8001/api/v1/feeds/list/?${page ? `page=${page}&` : ''}${query ? `search=${query}` : ''}`);
}
```

If possible, make your API accept empty query parameters too, allowing you to simplify to

```
return api.get(`http://localhost:8001/api/v1/feeds/list/?page=${page}&query=${query}`);
```

Comment: how will my `useEffect(()` will look like now?

Comment: Like the answer says, pass in an object instead. `fetchFeed({ query: search })` instead of `searchQuery(search)` for example, same technique for the other one

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work for you

```
const fetchFeed = async (page, query) => {
  let url =`http://localhost:8001/api/v1/feeds/list/?page=${page}`
  if(query) url += `?search=${query}`
  return api.get(url)
}

const browse = (page search) =>  {
   await fetchFeed(page search)
      .then(function(response){
       !search && setfeedCount(response.data.count)
       setFeed(response.data.results)
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      });
}

useEffect(() => {
    browse(currentPage) // just pass page
    browse(currentPage, searchQuery); // pass both page and search query
    }, [currentPage]);
```